# How to check whether a pointer is pointing to an element inside an array?

Tags: c, pointers

The following function intends to check whether the pointer `b` is pointing to the array `a[0],...,a[len-1]`?

```
bool between(int *a, int len, int *b)
{
    return (a <= b) && (b < a + len);
}
```

From reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison the function invokes undefined behaviour. If so, what is the right way to do this? Why does the standard disallow this?

Comment: What is your interpretation of the web page that causes you to consider this to be undefined behavior?

Comment: If you turn on all the compiler warnings (`-Wall`) do you get any warnings?

Comment: There is no standard-compliant method that does not involve UB.

Comment: @EvilTeach The part in pointer comparison indicates that any comparisons not in the list given are UB.

Comment: @Balagopal Komarath Consider posting an example of `between()` for alternative approachs to solve the higher level goal.

Comment: Would going `( b < &a[len] )` be less scary?  Then it's more plainly just pointer to pointer.

Comment: @infixed `b < &a[len]` is **exactl**y the same as `b < a + len`

Comment: The quandary is if you have `a` and the number of elements `len`, then from where in your code would you get `b` and not know whether `b` lies within `a`?

Comment: @dbush, yeah it is, but it avoids the scary plus sign in the scary pointer arithmetic.  :)  Some people think of pointer arithmetic as scary because of the sins it can lead to,  buffer overflows, page faults, etc.  (I also think its intent is more obvious when reading the code, but that's just my opinion)

Comment: @chux There is no higher level goal that is more specific. The intent is to check whether a pointer points into an array, as stated in the question.

Comment: @BalagopalKomarath What he means is that knowing why you need to do this check could lead to redesigning things so you don't have to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comparing two unrelated pointers (i.e. pointers that don't point to members of the same array object or struct) using the comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` do indeed invoke undefined behavior as described in the linked page as well as section 6.5.8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

As to why this is disallowed, not all implementations have a flat memory model, and unrelated objects need not reside in areas of memory where performing a comparison makes sense.

So your function would return true in cases where `b` points to a member of `a`, false when it points one past the last member of `a`, and would invoke undefined behavior otherwise.

It is however allowed to compare unrelated pointers using `==` or `!=`.  So you can circumvent the limitation on comparison operators by looping through the array and using equality operators to compare the target pointer with each element:

```
bool between(int *a, int len, int *b)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (a+i == b) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

While this is not a efficient as a ranged check, it is the only compliant way to do so.

Of course, it would be better to construct your program in such a way that such a comparison is not necessary.  A program that is allowing a pointer to inside an array to fall outside of the array is already invoking undefined behavior, so fixing that would eliminate the need for such a function.

Note however that it *is* allowed to increment a pointer to one element past the end of an array and perform comparisons on that pointer (although it cannot be dereferenced).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935415/2410359) good answer, code can do math on the array side `a` to achieve a potential quicker positive result.

By attempting a binary search first, if the outcome of `between()` is `true` and the mapping of pointers to integers are in a common implementation, the `true` value will be found in O(log(n)) time.

If `b` is not found in the array via the binary search, a linear is still needed to cope with unusual mapping of pointers to integers.

For large arrays, like `n=1,000,000` the log2(1,000,000) steps of doing a `bsearch` is insignificant.  For small arrays, best to proceed directly to the loop.

```
 // When optional, but common, uintptr_t available
int fcmp(const void *key, const void *array_element) {
  if (key == array_element) {
    return 0;
  }
  uintptr_t ai = (uintptr_t) array_element;
  uintptr_t ki = (uintptr_t) key;
  return (ai > ki) - (ai < ki);
}

// Best to use `size_t` for array indexing
bool between(int *a, size_t a_sz, int *b) {
  if (bsearch(b, a, a_sz, sizeof *a, fcmp)) {
    return true;
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a_sz; i++) {
    if (a + i == b) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```